# Specifying minimal (not fixed) width in tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, columns

I want some columns in my tables to have a minimal column width, that should always be maintained, even if the content is smaller, but increased when the content is wider.

**Bounty-related update**: @Sandy G's  answer produces the desired behavior,  but I want it to be a column type so that I can specify it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{2cm}m{1cm}m{1cm}}
    Longer entry here&2&3&4\\
    5&6&Longer entry here&8
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty to Steven's solution, because the bounty was explicitly for a solution that defines a new column-type. However, credit is also due to Sandy G's solution, which was however already there before the bounty started

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See **ADDENDUM** and **BONUS**

First, the original approach.

Here is a `\newcolumntype` solution, except that, for a reason that I should know but I don't, it won't work in the last column of the `tabular`.  I'm sure David C. could tell me off the cuff why.

So I've provided `C{}`, `L{}`, and `R{}` column types for specifying a minimum width, and an `Q` column type to use for a phantom, to get around the deficiency I initially cited.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,stackengine}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\minwd l{#1}}l<{\endminwd}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\minwd c{#1}}c<{\endminwd}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\minwd r{#1}}r<{\endminwd}}
\def\minwd#1#2#3\endminwd{\stackengine{0pt}{#3}{\rule{#2}{0pt}}{O}{#1}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcolumntype{Q}{@{}c@{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|C{1.2cm}|C{1.2cm}|R{2cm}|l|}
a & a& b& c\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa& aa& bb& cc\\
\end{tabular}
\bigskip


\begin{tabular}{|C{1.2cm}|C{1.2cm}|R{2cm}|L{1.5cm}|Q}
a & a& b& c&\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa& aa& bb& cc&\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ADDENDUM**

Apparently the way to overcome the deficiency I noted in my original solution is to use `\collectcell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,stackengine,collcell}
\let\endminwd\relax
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\collectcell\xminwd l{#1}}l<{\endminwd\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\collectcell\xminwd c{#1}}c<{\endminwd\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\collectcell\xminwd r{#1}}r<{\endminwd\endcollectcell}}
\def\minwd#1#2#3\endminwd{\stackengine{0pt}{#3}{\rule{#2}{0pt}}{O}{#1}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand\xminwd[1]{\minwd#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|C{1.2cm}|C{1.2cm}|R{2cm}|L{1.5cm}|}
a & a& b& c\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa& aa& bb& cc\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And just for fun, if you set the vertical measure of the `\rule` to something nonzero, say `1pt`, you can see how the rule comes into play:

[image]

---

**BONUS**

I realized the technique could be used for creating a `D` column for aligning a specified number of trailing decimal places.  EDITED to handle decimal free inputs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,stackengine,collcell}
\let\endecm\relax
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\collectcell\Decm l{#1}}r<{..\endDecm\endcollectcell}}
\def\decm#1#2#3.#4.#5\endDecm{#3.\stackengine{0pt}{#4}{\rule{#2\wd0}{0pt}}{O}{#1}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand\Decm[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{0}\decm#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|D{3}|D{2}|D{4}|}
10.345 & 410.34 & 1310.34\\
10 & 11 & 12.\\
210.34 & 1210.3 & 310.3456\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

This could be done by placing a row of `0pt` `\rule`s  with a negative row separator (for proper vertical alignment).

[image]

In the example, columns 1 and 2 have minimum width `2cm`, while columns 3 and 4 have minimum width 1cm.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\rule{2cm}{0pt}&\rule{2cm}{0pt}&\rule{1cm}{0pt}&\rule{1cm}{0pt}\\[-\arraystretch\normalbaselineskip]]
Longer entry here&2&3&4\\
5&6&Longer entry here&8
\end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Update**:
By placing the `\rule` in a macro, you can adjust the fixed minimum in the document body similarly to a column type.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fixedmin}[1]{\rule{#1}{0pt}&\rule{#1}{0pt}&\rule{#1}{0pt}&\rule{#1}{0pt}\\[-\arraystretch\normalbaselineskip]}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is a table with fixed minimum width 2 cm.
\[
\begin{tabular}{cccc}\fixedmin{2cm}
Longer entry here&2&3&4\\
5&6&Longer entry here&8
\end{tabular}
\]

\noindent Here is a table with fixed minimum width 1 cm.
\[
\begin{tabular}{cccc}\fixedmin{1cm}
Longer entry here&2&3&4\\
5&6&Longer entry here&8
\end{tabular}
\]

\noindent Here is a table with no fixed minimum width.
\[
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
Longer entry here&2&3&4\\
5&6&Longer entry here&8
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. Is there an easy way to make this a column type?

Comment: Nice update. I still hope though that someone will find a way to make this a columntype

Comment: That's a nice low-tech solution.

Comment: Instead of `\rule` it's cleaner to just use `\hspace*`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to do it using the `collcell` package. The idea is to measure the content of the cell and then add rules to make up the deficit where appropriate. I've made versions for `c`, `r` and `l` columns.  The vertical lines are just there to show the fixed width columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,calc,collcell}
\newlength{\fwlen}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\setlength{\fwlen}{#1}\collectcell\fixedCwidth}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\setlength{\fwlen}{#1}\collectcell\fixedRwidth}r<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\setlength{\fwlen}{#1}\collectcell\fixedLwidth}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fixedCwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tempdima}{\widthof{#1}}\ifdim\@tempdima>\fwlen #1\else\setlength{\@tempdimb}{(\fwlen-\@tempdima)/2}\rule{\@tempdimb}{0pt}#1\rule{\@tempdimb}{0pt}\fi}
\newcommand{\fixedLwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tempdima}{\widthof{#1}}\ifdim\@tempdima>\fwlen #1\else\setlength{\@tempdimb}{\fwlen-\@tempdima}#1\rule{\@tempdimb}{0pt}\fi}
\newcommand{\fixedRwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tempdima}{\widthof{#1}}\ifdim\@tempdima>\fwlen #1\else\setlength{\@tempdimb}{\fwlen-\@tempdima}\rule{\@tempdimb}{0pt}#1\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|C{1cm}|L{1cm}|R{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|}
123 &   123 &   123 &   123 & This is a wider column\\
5   &   6   &   6   &   8 & 8
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of cod]

Answer (score 1):

To do it properly, you need a minimum width and a maximum width of each column. You required the minimum width in your question. I'd say, it is better to have a maximum width, because otherwise your tabular might run out of the margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{varwidth}% varwidth defines a new column type V.

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{V{4cm}}}
\hspace*{2cm} & \hspace*{2cm} & \hspace*{1cm} & \hspace*{1cm}\\[-1em]
    Longer entry here&2&3&4\\
    5&6&Longer entry here, which gets wrapped finaly&8\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

There are two small tricks.

First, the varwidth package defines a new column type, but this is not documented in the manual, I found it here: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-varwidcol

`V{4cm}`sets the maximum width of a column.

Second: we need a minimum width. We just can take an empty line of the tabular and fill it with empty spaces of the needed minimum width. To hide this line, I inserted `\\[-1em]`, which you need to adapt in your use case. I suggest to put it as first line of the tabular, followed by the head of the tabular, not the other way round.

Hopefully it works in your use case!

[image: pic of tabular]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. You seem to be answering a slightly different question though. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "to do it properly"? How is ruining out of the margins a problem related to setting a minimum width? Doesn't this also happen with a plain `\begin{tabular}{cccc}`-table?

Comment: @sheß Yes, any column of the types c or l or r can become much to broad. So I prefer the p or b or m column type!