# siunitx, brackets around negative numbers

Tags: tables, siunitx

writing tables with statistics result often contain negative numbers in brackets, for example `(-1.23)`, which should be aligned on the decimal point with other numbers in columns. this can be (simply) accomplished by `S`column option `parse-numbers=false`, however this option disables most of the other options of the `S` column (see first example in *mwe* below)

another possibilities, which cross my mind is defined robust command, for example `\brckt` and use it instead of `(`. this approach works fine, i.e. preserve all `S` column options (see the second example in *mwe*), however i wonder, if any one know for better solution. so far my search on this site did not yield to better solution.

the (not so) minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}                      % used in second example
\newrobustcmd{\brckt}{(}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {( )},             % has no sense
         table-space-text-pre={(},          % has no effect ...
         table-align-text-pre=false,        % has no effect ...
         table-space-text-post={$^{***}$},  % has no effect ...
         table-align-text-post=false,       % has no effect ...
         round-mode = places,               % has no sense
%         round-precision = 3               % make error
         parse-numbers=false,               % <---
        }
\begin{threeparttable}[htb]
\caption{first example}
\label{tab:statistic}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{S[table-format=-2.3]}}% integer part had to have
                                           % one digit more than normally needed
                                           % other vice decimal point is overwritten
    \toprule
1.23\tnote{*}   & 1.234 \tnote{**}  & 1.2345\tnote{***} \\
(9.87)          &   (-7.89)         &   (-7.89)         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para]
    \item[*]    text;
    \item[**]   text;
    \item[**]   text.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {( - )},
         table-space-text-pre={(},
         table-align-text-pre=false,
         table-space-text-post={$^{***}$},
         table-align-text-post=false,
         round-mode = places,
         round-precision = 3
        }
\begin{threeparttable}[htb]
\caption{second example}
\label{tab:statistic}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{S[table-format=-1.3]} }
    \toprule
1.23\tnote{*}   & 1.234 \tnote{**}  & 1.2345\tnote{***} \\
(9.87)          & \brckt-7.89)      & \brckt-7.89)      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para]
    \item[*]    text;
    \item[**]   text;
    \item[**]   text.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between the tables (except a typo for the number in the last cell of the first row)?

Comment: @Bernard, as i say in the question: in the first example is not possible to use the most of `S` column options (since they are disabled -- as expected -- by `parse-numbers=false`). the problem is, how to obtain for example  `(-1.234)` and preserve `S` column options for number formatting. not using `parse-numbers=false` cause error. in second example i try to avoid it by defining robust command for `(`, but solution is somehow rude.

Answer (score 2):

Based on an answer I recently gave at [Specifying minimal (not fixed) width in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402414/specifying-minimal-not-fixed-width-in-tabular/478054#478054), that was capable of aligning at decimal points (without using `siunitx`), I took that code and significantly extended it to allow for parentheses and `\tnote`s (only `)` and `\tnote`s may appear after the decimal point!).  The extended code also performs numerical rounding (in native LaTeX).

The method creates a `D{}` column, with the argument denoting the number of digits allowed to follow the decimal point.

Again, I stress that this method operates outside of `siunitx`, and so the only features it provides are limited to decimal alignment, surrounding the numerical arguments in parens, and the use of a trailing `\tnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,stackengine,collcell,booktabs,threeparttable}
\let\endecm\relax
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{%
  >{\catcode`)=\active \collectcell\Decm l{#1}}r<{..\endDecm\endcollectcell}}
\def\decm#1#2#3.#4.#5\endDecm{%
  $#3.$%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine%
  {0pt}{\truncdig{#4}{#2}}{\rule{#2\wd0}{0pt}}{O}{#1}{F}{F}{L}}}
\newcommand\Decm[1]{\let\tnote\specialtnote\setbox0=\hbox{0}\decm#1}
\newcommand\specialtnote[1]{\rlap{$^{#1}$}}
\let\svrp)
{\catcode`)=\active
\gdef){\rlap{\svrp}}
}
\newcommand\truncdig[2]{\truncdigaux{#2}#1\relax\relax}
\def\truncdigaux#1#2#3\relax{%
  \ifx\tnote#2#2{#3}\else
    \if\svrp\detokenize{#2}\rlap{)}\else
      \ifnum#1>1\relax
        #2%
      \else
       \ifnum#1>0\relax
         \roundit#2#3\relax\relax
       \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    \ifx\relax#3\else
      \expandafter\truncdigaux\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}#3\relax
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\roundit#1#2#3\relax{
  \ifx\tnote#2#1\else
    \ifx\relax#2#1\else
      \if\svrp\detokenize{#2}#1\else
        \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter`\detokenize\expandafter{#2}<53\relax#1\else
          \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter`\detokenize\expandafter{#2}>57\relax#1\else
            \the\numexpr#1+1%
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\tabcolsep=15pt\relax
\begin{tabular}{D{2}D{3}D{3}}
    \toprule
1.23\tnote{*}   & 1.234 \tnote{**}  & 1.2345\tnote{***} \\
(9.87)          &   (-7.89)         &   (-7.89)         \\
13.375          &   (-43.2759)         &   1.234         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para]
    \item[*]    text;
    \item[**]   text;
    \item[**]   text.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{document}
```

The following table, asking for columns with 2, 3, and 3 post-decimal digits, is thus produced from these inputs:

```
1.23\tnote{*}   & 1.234 \tnote{**}  & 1.2345\tnote{***} \\
(9.87)          &   (-7.89)         &   (-7.89)         \\
13.375          &   (-43.2759)         &   1.234         \\
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for answer! nice workaround (+1) , however, as you point out yourself, it not use ˙siunitx˙` (unfortunately). i expect that required robustness for `(` will be solved on more elegant way as i show in question or even be incorporated to  `siunitx` package (since such tables are quite common).

Comment: @Zarko I knew as much going in, but my recollection of my earlier approach seemed too good to pass up.  Mostly, I wanted to see if I could make a go of it.

Comment: On related recent question I upvoted you :-)