# Negative sign in regression Table

Tags: tables

I need some help with building regression tables estimation previously found in this forum
what I wanted is to include the negative sign between parentheses where also the dot is clear

Here the code I used

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
 \usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
 \newcommand{\Risk}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Risk}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\COP}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CO\_P}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\Bdin}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Bd\_in}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\OP}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OP}}\nolimits}
 \newcommand{\OF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OF}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\lZ}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape lZ}}\nolimits}
 \begin{document}
  \centering

    \sisetup{input-symbols = {( - )},
         table-space-text-post=***,
         }
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Risk}
  \label{tab:min}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
             *{6}{S[table-format=3.3]}
                                    }
    \toprule
     &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Credit risk (Ns):}}
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Insolvency risk (Log):}}  \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{5-7}
     & {\makecell[b]{EQ}}
    & {\makecell[b]{EQ}}
        & {\makecell[b]{EQ}}
            & {\makecell[b]{EQ}}
                & {\makecell[b]{EQ}}
                    & {\makecell[b]{EQ}}  \\
 & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)}        \\
\midrule
Constant
   & 5.16             & -24.380\tnote{***}& 44.654\tnote{**}
   & 5.104\tnote{***} & -23.011\tnote{***}& -7.523        \\
   & (-16.18)          & (-12.041)          & (-25.994)
   & (-17.35)          & (-4.429)           & (-7.563)       \\
   \addlinespace
NL_{it-1}
   & 0.33\tnote{***}   & -1.760            & -14.021\tnote{*}
   &                   &                   &          \\
  & (-2.33)            & (-3.302)           & (-6.788)
  &                   &                   &        \\
   \addlinespace
lZ_{it-1}
  &                  &                   &  
  &  0.51\tnote{***} & 0.022             & -1.712\tnote{***}  \\
  &                  &                   &  
  & (5.83)           & (0.176)           & (0.388)       \\
  \addlinespace
 CO\_P_{it}
   & 6.48 \tnote{***}  & -6.143            & -2.835
   & 1.14             & -4.194\tnote{**}  & 2.595         \\
  & (11.47)           & (4.947)           & (9.834)
  & (1.42)            & (2.120)           & (3.570)       \\
   \addlinespace
 Bd\_in
   & -0.402 \tnote{***}  & -6.143            & -2.835
   & -0.451 \tnote{***}  & -4.454\tnote{**}  & 2.595         \\
   & (-2.6)             & (4.947)           & (9.834)
   & (-9.01)             & (2.120)           & (3.570)       \\
   \addlinespace
  OF
  & 172.346\tnote{***}& -5.395            & 112.881\tnote{***}
  & 34.885\tnote{***} & 0.746             & 19.181\tnote{***}  \\
  & (10.328)          & (7.163)           & (11.468)
  & (4.545)           & (3.050)           & (4.082)       \\
  \addlinespace
 OP
   & 44.392\tnote{***} & 30.974\tnote{***} &
   & 7.323\tnote{**}   & 3.750             &               \\
   & (8.366)           & (5.803)           &
   & (3.704)           & (2.485)           &               \\
    \addlinespace
 CO\_P_{it}*OF_{i,t}
   & 14.358            & 11.918            & 13.574
   & 2.479             & 0.665             & -1.509        \\
   & (14.103)          & (9.782)           & (35.007)
   & (6.961)           & (4.671)           & (12.953)      \\
  \addlinespace
CO\_P_{it}*OP_{i,t}
   & 11.746            & 1.660             & 26.062
& 6.437             & 1.397             & -1.739        \\
& (15.879)          & (11.014)          & (36.345)
& (7.461)           & (5.006)           & (13.706)      \\
\addlinespace
   Bd\_in_{i,t}*OF_{i,t}
   & 0.735             & -3.638            & 9.136
   & -1.743            & 1.624             & -4.717        \\
   & (10.900)          & (7.561)           & (16.345)
   & (4.476)           & (3.003)           & (5.476)       \\
   \addlinespace
    Bd\_ind_{i,t}*OP_{i,t}
     & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
     & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
     & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
     & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
     \addlinespace
      Size 
      & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
      & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
      & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
      & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
     \addlinespace
      Capitalization
       & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
       & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
       & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
       & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
       \addlinespace
       liquidity 
       & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
       & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
       & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
       & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
       Profitability 
        & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
        & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
        & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
        & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
        Efficiency
        & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
        & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
        & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
       & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
       Leverage ratio 
        & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
        & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
        & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
        & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
      Loan growth 
        & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
        & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
        & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
        & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
       Asset growth 
        & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
        & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
        & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
        & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
      Price growth 
        & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
        & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
        & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
        & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
     Diversification 
      & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
      & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
      & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
      & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
       \midrule
       Year dummy
        & {Yes }            & {Yes }           & {Yes }
        & {Yes }            & {Yes }           & {Yes }       \\
      R$\tnote{2}$
       & {0.546}           & {0.314}           & {0.367}
       & {0.178}           & {0.112}           & {0.155}       \\
       Adjusted R$\tnote{2}$
          & {0.543}           & {0.309}           & {0.361} 
          & {0.173}           & {0.106}           & {0.147}       \\
       Sargan test 
          & 146.365           & 101.519           & 144.965
          & 65.110            & 43.686            & 52.256        \\
         \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
       \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, para]\footnotesize
      \note: \item[*] $p<$0.1; \item[**] $p<0.05$; \item[***] $p<0.01$
         \end{tablenotes}
     \end{threeparttable}

     \end{document}
```

The outcome :

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479494/134144 could be interesting. Alternatively you could also try `\sisetup{parse-numbers=false}`.

Comment: Apart from that, your table is too large for a single page. Either decrease some vertical spacing or allow the table to spann more than one page (see `longtable`).