# Alignment of bracketed negatives in an siunitx table

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to typeset a financial statement in LaTeX. I am using the siunitx package with the bracket-negative-numbers option to achieve this, but I'm struggling to get the alignment to work how I would like in the table. (That is, aligned by the decimal separator but with that separator mostly to the right, rather than in the centre.)

A minimal example might be:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-digits = integer}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 4}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | S[table-format = -4.2, bracket-negative-numbers] |}
\hline
Income (net) & -1657.37\\
\hline
Cashflow from operations & 1200.63\\
\hline
Investment return & -2858.00\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Illustration of the output from the above code]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450026/siunitx-brackets-around-negative-numbers