# How to align numbers on decimal points? Please explain the meaning of the code

Tags: horizontal-alignment

My table:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Question}
\label{tab:q}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lclclclcl@{}}
\toprule
                        & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Event 1}}      & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Event 2}}    \\ \cmidrule(l){2-9} 
\textbf{}               & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Prob} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Amount} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Prob} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Amount} \\ \midrule
\textbf{Graduation}     & 0.1482        & ***      & 487.17         &         & $-0.2209$        & ***     & $-1,613.31$      & ***      \\
\textbf{}               & (0.0409)      &          & (520.14)       &         & (0.0491)       &         & (396.12)      &          \\
\textbf{First job}      & 0.1174        & ***      & 2,891.29       & **       & -0.1756        & ***     & $-1,516.49$      & ***      \\
\textbf{}               & (0.0312)      &          & (1283.82)       &         & (0.0319)       &         & (517.66)      &          \\
\textbf{First marriage} & $-0.0246$       &          & $-1,780.18$       & **      & 0.0413         & ***      & 379.59        &  ***        \\
\textbf{}               & (0.0168)      &          & (656.93)       &         & (0.0140)       &         & (131.73)      &          \\
\textbf{First child}    & $-0.0514$       & **        & $-369.90$        &         & 0.0808         & ***     & 1,234.24        & **        \\
                        & (0.0243)      &          & (1328.18)       &         & (0.0206)       &         & (603.08)      &          \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{Standard errors are in parentheses.}                                                                                                                                                              
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I want the numbers to be aligned by decimal points. I know this question is frequently asked, but I cannot reproduce the code on my table since I do not understand what the code like `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}` or `\begin{tabular}{l *{4}{d{3.3}} }` means.

Edit: Shoutout to Steven! I can reproduce the results now!

Comment: Most people use the S column from siunitx (page 15).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I use an approach I set out in the **BONUS** section of this answer: [Specifying minimal (not fixed) width in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402414/specifying-minimal-not-fixed-width-in-tabular/478054#478054).  I created by own `D` column type that takes an argument that specifies the max number of digits following the decimal point (here, the right paren counts as a digit).  The only change I needed to your input was to isolate the minus signs in their own math group, as in `$-$xx.xx` rather than include the complete cell entry in math, as in `$-xx.xx$`, since the parser needs to separate the pre-decimal content from the post-decimal content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,stackengine,collcell,booktabs}
\let\endecm\relax
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\collectcell\Decm l{#1}}r<%
  {..\endDecm\endcollectcell}}
\def\decm#1#2#3.#4.#5\endDecm{#3.%
  \stackengine{0pt}{#4}{\rule{#2\wd0}{0pt}}{O}{#1}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand\Decm[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{0}\decm#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lD{5}lD{3}lD{5}lD{3}l@{}}
\toprule
                        & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Event 1}}      & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Event 2}}    \\ \cmidrule(l){2-9} 
\textbf{}               & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Prob} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Amount} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Prob} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Amount} \\ \midrule
\textbf{Graduation}     & 0.1482        & ***      & 487.17         &         & $-$0.2209        & ***     & $-$1,613.31      & ***      \\
\textbf{}               & (0.0409)      &          & (520.14)       &         & (0.0491)       &         & (396.12)      &          \\
\textbf{First job}      & 0.1174        & ***      & 2,891.29       & **       & $-$0.1756        & ***     & $-$1,516.49      & ***      \\
\textbf{}               & (0.0312)      &          & (1283.82)       &         & (0.0319)       &         & (517.66)      &          \\
\textbf{First marriage} & $-$0.0246       &          & $-$1,780.18       & **      & 0.0413         & ***      & 379.59        &  ***        \\
\textbf{}               & (0.0168)      &          & (656.93)       &         & (0.0140)       &         & (131.73)      &          \\
\textbf{First child}    & $-$0.0514       & **        & $-$369.90        &         & 0.0808         & ***     & 1,234.24        & **        \\
                        & (0.0243)      &          & (1328.18)       &         & (0.0206)       &         & (603.08)      &          \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{9}{l}{Standard errors are in parentheses.}                                                                                                                                                              
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If you don't mind, could you take a look at my new question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686843/how-to-align-numbers-by-decimal-points-but-still-keep-the-words-centered