# How to align numbers by decimal points but still keep the words centered?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

A follow up to this question: [How to align numbers on decimal points? Please explain the meaning of the code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686800/how-to-align-numbers-on-decimal-points-please-explain-the-meaning-of-the-code)

My table:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{question}
\label{tab:q}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccl}
\hline
        & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Pooled OLS}}  \\ 
\cline{2-7} 
     & (1)   &  & (2)     &         & (3)    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  \\
       & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Outcome variable}}   \\ 
\hline
\textit{\textbf{Group 1}}      &                       &                          &                       &                          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  &                       \\
\textbf{Treatment}      & 0.0929                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{***}  & 0.0615                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{***}  & 0.0548                & **                    \\
\textbf{}                      & (0.0177)              &                          & (0.0173)              &                          & (0.0177)              &                       \\
\textbf{Base control}       & No                    &                          & Yes                   &                          & Yes                   &                       \\
\textbf{Additional controls}   & No                    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}     & No                    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}     & Yes                   &                       \\
\textbf{Observations}          & 4,537                  &                          & 4,537                  &                          & 4,493                  &                       \\ \hline
\textit{\textbf{Group 2}}      &                       &                          &                       &                          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  &                       \\
\textbf{Treatment}      & $-$0.0078               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}     & $-$0.0323               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{***}  & $-$0.0354               & ***                   \\
\textbf{}                      & (0.0125)              &                          & (0.0123)              &                          & (0.01249)             &                       \\
\textbf{Base control}       & No                    &                          & Yes                   &                          & Yes                   &                       \\
\textbf{Additional controls}   & No                    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}     & No                    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}     & Yes                   &                       \\
\textbf{Observations}          & 5,401                  &                          & 5,401                  &                          & 5,383                  &                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors are in parentheses.}                                                                                                                                                                        
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I want to align the number with decimals by decimal points, but keep the words and integers centered. I followed @Steven B. Segletes yesterday by adding

```
\usepackage{tabularx,stackengine,collcell,booktabs}
\let\endecm\relax
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\collectcell\Decm l{#1}}r<%
  {..\endDecm\endcollectcell}}
\def\decm#1#2#3.#4.#5\endDecm{#3.%
  \stackengine{0pt}{#4}{\rule{#2\wd0}{0pt}}{O}{#1}{F}{F}{L}}
\newcommand\Decm[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{0}\decm#1}
```

and change `\begin{tabular}{lcccccl}` to `\begin{tabular}{lD{5}cD{5}cD{5}l}`

But then the `Yes` and `No` and the observation numbers are not centered.

Comment: I added a pointer to the prior question.  Also, as a rule, you should not just provide code snippets, but rather a Minimum Working Example (MWE) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and compiles, showing the issue at hand.

Comment: When a column is made of type `D{}`, **all** the data entries of that column are expected to be of decimal form.  By trying to add rows containing either text or integer data, you violate the basic construct for a "Decimal" column.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Does this mean that the `D{}` method doesn't apply here?

Comment: I would have to say that yes, the `D{}` method does **not** apply if some of the rows contain non-decimal entries in the column of interest.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to do it? :( @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: Please see my answer that modifies how `D{}` columns are treated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the `D` columns in the referenced answer ([How to align numbers on decimal points? Please explain the meaning of the code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686800/how-to-align-numbers-on-decimal-points-please-explain-the-meaning-of-the-code)) is that all entries in a `D` column are assumed to be decimal numbers.

Here, I have amended that answer so that a cell entry in a `D` column is first checked to see if it contains a decimal point.  If it does, it treats it as before.  If it does not, it merely presents the cell contents centered in box of width equal to 2 digits larger than the specified decimal width, which itself is right-aligned to the decimal entries in the column.

This approach is not a fix all, because the choice of "2 digits larger than the specified decimal width" is somewhat arbitrary and may not present nicely for all data.  Nonetheless it is an improvement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,stackengine,collcell,booktabs}
\let\endecm\relax
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\collectcell\Decm l{#1}}r<%
  {..\endDecm\endcollectcell}}
\def\decm#1#2#3.#4.#5\endDecm{\ifx\relax#4\relax
  \makebox[\numexpr2+#2\relax\wd0]{#3}\else
  #3.\stackengine{0pt}{#4}{\rule{#2\wd0}{0pt}}{O}{#1}{F}{F}{L}\fi}
\newcommand\Decm[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{0}\decm#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lD{5}cD{5}cD{6}l}\hline
        & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Pooled OLS}}  \\ 
\cline{2-7} 
     & (1)   &  & (2)     &         & (3)    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  \\
       & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Outcome variable}}   \\ 
\hline
\textit{\textbf{Group 1}}      &                       &                          &                       &                          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  &                       \\
\textbf{Treatment}      & 0.0929                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{***}  & 0.0615                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{***}  & 0.0548                & **                    \\
\textbf{}                      & (0.0177)              &                          & (0.0173)              &                          & (0.0177)              &                       \\
\textbf{Base control}       & No                    &                          & Yes                   &                          & Yes                   &                       \\
\textbf{Additional controls}   & No                    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}     & No                    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}     & Yes                   &                       \\
\textbf{Observations}          & 4,537                  &                          & 4,537                  &                          & 4,493                  &                       \\ \hline
\textit{\textbf{Group 2}}      &                       &                          &                       &                          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  &                       \\
\textbf{Treatment}      & $-$0.0078               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}     & $-$0.0323               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{***}  & $-$0.0354               & ***                   \\
\textbf{}                      & (0.0125)              &                          & (0.0123)              &                          & (0.01249)             &                       \\
\textbf{Base control}       & No                    &                          & Yes                   &                          & Yes                   &                       \\
\textbf{Additional controls}   & No                    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}     & No                    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}     & Yes                   &                       \\
\textbf{Observations}          & 5,401                  &                          & 5,401                  &                          & 5,383                  &                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors are in parentheses.}                                                                                                                                                                        
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]